# .less styles don't make it into built React App

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, less

There is an imported component in my React App that comes with .less styles ([this one](https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-range-picker)). For as long as I've worked on the app, I simply imported the .less from inside the modules' styles folder and left it at that. Like this:

```
import './../../../node_modules/rsuite/lib/styles/index.less';
```

This was comfortable as it resulted in a font change and some other formatting which I liked at the time, so I just ran with it.
However, I recently made a production build of the App (using `npm run-script build`, which took some work in itself, including getting rid of `webpack`, maybe that's the reason) and noticed that the .less styles didn't make it into the fully built bundle.js. All my custom .css is there, but the imported component is unstyled.

I can't really get to the bottom of it. I tried setting the "dev" property of the `less` package in package.json to `false` and also tried converting the .less to .css myself, but it's a pretty complex structure and I'm not confident I could rebuild it.

How can I make sure the imported styles get carried over (and, if I can't, what else can I do to get the styles into the fully built version of the App?)

Comment: You can just import the css not the `.less` from it's dist or build dir in the node_modules. Library authors typically include the build in their package

Comment: That's amazing, you're right. Thanks!